# WhatsApp API doenst open the contact linked in URL

Tags: javascript, api, http, whatsapp

I have a link with the API click to chat from whatsapp. The button with the link have the URL https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5527998497670&text=Hello.

It works on mobile devices and desktops that have the application installed. For browser's users, the API open the Web WhatsApp but it doesnt open the contact linked in the URL.

I've tried to use //wa.me/phone_number too.

EDIT:
I saw it in others posts that is a problema with whatsapp web server.

WhatsApp

Comment: Have you tired to log in into `web.whatsapp.com` before clicking the link? Does it give you the same issue?

Comment: See [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56378715/3473122) **Started working again**

Answer (score 0):

The phone is not indicated like a standard `GET` param.  It should actually be like so...

```
https://wa.me/12345?text=My+Test+Text!
```

The phone number appears before the `text=` param.  Give it a try.